# Htacces index.php?this_path=$1

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

Help to translate htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(^[^.]+)$ /index.php?this_path=$1 [L]
```

Convector site (http://winginx.ru/htaccess) takes me to:

```
location / {
rewrite ^/(^[^.]+)$ /index.php?this_path=$1 break;
}
```

In error.log apache

```
2013/11/08 16:29:28 [error] 23867#0: *30 "/var/www/site.ru/web/tourfirms/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 92.248.243.0, server: site.ru, request: "GET /tourfirms/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.site.ru"
```

Config nginx

```
server {
listen *:80;

server_name site.ru www.site.ru;

root /var/www/site.ru/web;

index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;

error_page 400 /error/400.html;
error_page 401 /error/401.html;
error_page 403 /error/403.html;
error_page 404 /error/404.html;
error_page 405 /error/405.html;
error_page 500 /error/500.html;
error_page 502 /error/502.html;
error_page 503 /error/503.html;
recursive_error_pages on;
location = /error/400.html {

internal;
}
location = /error/401.html {

internal;
}
location = /error/403.html {

internal;
}
location = /error/404.html {

internal;
}
location = /error/405.html {

internal;
}
location = /error/500.html {

internal;
}
location = /error/502.html {

internal;
}
location = /error/503.html {

internal;
}

error_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/site.ru/error.log;
access_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/site.ru/access.log combined;

location ~ /\. {
deny all;
access_log off;
log_not_found off;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
log_not_found off;
access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
allow all;
log_not_found off;
access_log off;
}

location /stats {

index index.html index.php;
auth_basic "Members Only";
auth_basic_user_file /var/www/site.ru/stats/.htpasswd_stats;
}

location ^~ /awstats-icon {
alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files /9d53b9291759bd903e7bd04ed227882a.htm @php;
}

location @php {
try_files $uri =404;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9021;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}

location / {
rewrite ^/(^[^.]+)$ /index.php?this_path=$1 break;
}

}
```

Comment: Please tell us: What is not working?

Comment: When you open the site, is just an empty field                    `127.0.0.1 - - [11/Nov/2013:13:12:59 +0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 14839 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
`